# jQuery window.width doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, smooth-scrolling

Works in Chrome and Safari, but not in FF 43.0.2.  Firefox ignores the`'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -100` line and scrolls directly to the anchor instead.  I'm pretty new to programming, so any improvements on the code structure are also appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = this.hash;
var $target = $(target);

if ($(window).width() < 769) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -100
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
    // Dropdown Menu Logic
        $('#nav-icon').toggleClass('open');
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -150
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
    // Dropdown Menu Logic
        $('#nav-icon').toggleClass('open');
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing $('html, body') with $('window')?

Comment: So does the rest of it work, sliding the UL etc. in Firefox ?

Comment: Everything else with the UL etc works perfectly.  In FF it scrolls to the offset, then resets to the original anchor--this is really interesting!  I have tried your suggestions, Mark, as well as changing syntax on the `$target.offset().top -100` to `$target.offset({top-100})` but this doesn't help.  Also, there is no margin or padding or borders on the body element, as jQuery .offset() will not support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine but when you change the `window.location` after the animation is over, Firefox "jumps" to the corresponding anchor. This is actually the desired behavior.

To avoid this artifact, use `history.pushState` instead and fallback to `location.hash` on unsupported browsers :)

```
if(history.pushState){
    history.pushState(null, null, target);
}else{
    location.hash = target;
}
```

An example: http://codepen.io/victmo/pen/dGNvay

Cheers